orthonormal basis equivalence
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Given an orthonormal list $\{e_\alpha\}$, then I am trying to show that these are equivalent
-The submodule generated by $\{e_\alpha:\alpha \in A\}$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$
-Given $x \in \mathcal{H}$, then $B := \{\alpha \in A: \langle x, e_\alpha \rangle \neq 0\}$ is countable(finite or countably infinite). If $B$ is countably infinite, then given any bijective function $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$, then $$x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \langle x, e_{g(n)} \rangle e_{g(n)}$$converges in $\mathcal{H}$.
Considering each closed subspace $\mathbb{C}e_\alpha$, we can consider the direct sum(which is an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$) $\sum \mathbb{C} e_\alpha$. This is clearly isomorphic to my submodule(vector space) generated from the collection $\{e_\alpha\}$. My algebra quite poor, what would the procedure be to show that $$\bigoplus \mathbb{C} e_\alpha \cong \overline{\text{span}\{e_\alpha:\alpha \in A\}}$$I think after showing this, then the proof seems straightforward above. One of the issues I think I have is if I pick some element $\xi \in \overline{\text{span}\{e_\alpha:\alpha \in A\}}$ it does not look pretty. P.S. I am aware of the equivalence statements to orthonormal basis in Folland

Your question is unclear to me. Do you want to show that if ${e_n}$ is an orthonormal basis so is ${e_{g(n)}}$ ?

@RyszardSzwarc It is to show that Hilbert space $\bigoplus \mathbb{C} e_\alpha$ is isomorphic to the closure of my vector space generated by the orthonormal basis. However, I am starting to realize some of my initial thinking is wrong. I understand the proofs of an orthonormal basis in Folland. In Pdersen Analysis Now, he defines orthonormal basis an orthonormal set such that span of this list is dense in our hilbert space, which I am trying to show these different definitions in Folland and Pedersen are equivalent.

I am going to assume that by $\sum_{\alpha \in A}\mathbb{C} e_{\alpha}$ you are referring to the algebraic internal direct sum of the vector subspaces $\{\mathbb{C}e_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$, so that $\sum_{\alpha \in A}\mathbb{C} e_{\alpha} = \text{span}(\{e_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\})$. I will also assume that by $\oplus_{\alpha\in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}$ you are referring to the Hilbert space obtained with the vector space $\{ (x_{\alpha}e_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A} \in \prod_{\alpha\in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha} : \sum_{\alpha \in A} \|x_{\alpha}\|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} < \infty \}$ equipped with the inner product $\langle (x_{\alpha}e_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}, (y_{\alpha}e_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}\rangle := \sum_{\alpha\in A} x_{\alpha} \overline{y_{\alpha}}$.
It is indeed true that the closure of $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}$ in $\mathcal{H}$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}$. To see this, note that the correspondence of every $(x_{\alpha}c_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ in $\oplus_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}$ with the element $\sum_{\alpha\in A}x_{\alpha}e_{\alpha}$ in $\overline{\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}}^{\mathcal{H}}$ is an isometric isomorphism between the two Hilbert spaces.
However, you don't need to use this here. Instead, to show the direction you are asking about, observe that as $\sum_{\alpha\in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}$ is the submodule generated by $\{e_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$, it is sufficient to show that $\mathcal{H} = \overline{\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}}^{\mathcal{H}}$.
Let $x\in \mathcal{H}$. Then $B = \{\alpha \in A : \langle x, e_{\alpha} \rangle \neq 0 \}$ is countable. If $B$ is finite, then $x\in \sum_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C} e_{\alpha}$ and the result is clear. Otherwise, suppose $B$ is infinite. Let $g:\mathbb{N} \to B$ be a bijective function. By assumption,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left\| x - \sum_{n=0}^{N} \langle x, e_{g(n)}\rangle e_{g(n)} \right\|_{\mathcal{H}} = 0.$$
Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\left\| x - \sum_{n=0}^{N} \langle x, e_{g(n)}\rangle e_{g(n)} \right\|_{\mathcal{H}} < \varepsilon .$$
This shows that $x\in \overline{\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}}^{\mathcal{H}}$ and consequently $\mathcal{H} = \overline{\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C}e_{\alpha}}^{\mathcal{H}}$.

This makes sense thanks. I know that natural map from $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{C} e_\alpha$ to submodule generated by ${e_\alpha: \alpha \in A}$ is a homeomorphism. It is true when I take the completion of both of these spaces they should also have a homeomorphism?  Assuming that the span is dense, then we then have the completion of the direct sum of $\mathbb{C} e_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to the closure of the span( which is equal to $\mathcal{H}$ from assumption).This should immediately finish the proof.

I was able to figure out the isometric isomorphism between the completion of the direct sum and the closure of the generated submodule.

I realized that if we have a isometric isomorphism, then it is immediately a homeomorphism too.

I added some information about that in the answer. As you said, it can be shown that there is an isometric isomorphism between the two Hilbert spaces.
